# Sum unordered data across multiple sheets

Tags: vba, excel-formula

I think sumproduct sumifs indirect is what I need but I fail to see how to construct it;(
I have a workbook for logging volunteer hours.

I'm summing up the monthly hours (12 sheets/tables) to FY Totals sheet/table with hours by volunteer. So the sheet/table that I want to use the formula in is FY TOTALS

The workbook consists of 14 sheets:
sheet(VOLUNTEERS) has a table(tbl_volunteers) It contains data about the volunteer and the 1st 3 columns are duplicated on all 13 sheets (12 monthly and 1 FY totals) 
A5[Status]  B5[LastName]  C5[Firstname]

The Month sheets have the above fields followed by 5 categories with hours per category for each volunteer

The sheet/table FY Totals is identical to Monthly, but I want the categories to sum all 12 months for each volunteer.

So I need to match criteria of [LastName][FirstName] and sum values in [category]D:I

I can send a copy of the file, but not load images here;(

Comment: Can I clarify your question? Do you have 12 sheets which have identical setup and you are just trying to sum up values across all 12 sheets?

Comment: yes, I tried to just SUM across sheets but if the sheets are sorted differently,  (the same name is not in the same row) I get the wrong volunteer data. SO I need to MATCH the FIRST & LAST NAME (col B/C) in each sheet and add values from col D

Comment: I think this can be done well without needing complicated formulas. I've posted as an answer -- do let me know if it works for you?

Comment: I would love to use a pivot, but...I also have a value called LIFETIME hours I need to add to the mix. I'm not sure how to include this value in a pivot...

Answer (score 0):

You could use multiple consolidated ranges.

[image]

Notice that I have four different ranges. These could have been in different worksheets and the names aren't necessarily in the same order. A pivot table has been created that sums the hours worked for each person as requested. In this example, they just happen to be the same.

**How?**

1. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> (windows) or <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> (mac)
2. Select *multiple consolidated ranges*, then *Next*
3. Select *Create a single page field for me*, then *Next*
4. *Add* each of your ranges one by one, then *Finish*

**Update**

There's so much more you can do with PivotTables, as per your comments -- you can separate out data by creating  **your own page fields**. Do this instead of step 3 above

3. Select *I will create the page fields*, then *Next*
4. For each range you select and add, click '1' page field and type the description of that data, for example `2016 Data`, or `2017 Data`
5. (Optional) Your fields will automatically be put into the report filter field. You might want to drag it into Row Labels field (below Row) to get the view below

You can then see the split of the different fields you used in your PivotTable - in yellow I have my 2016 data and you can see it's been split out in the PivotTable.

[image]

Comment: I would love to use a pivot for this, but I also need to add previous year LIFETIME hours to the annual hours for the summary, and don't see how to do that in a pivot.....I may try to add another sheet with just LIFETIME and add it to the MIX?  I also have to get counts by category (sub totals). and there are 5. wish I could snapshot in here....

Comment: Ive updated my answer, just to illustrate how you can potentially add lifetime hours, think it will work?

Comment: I worked on a pivot table all day! I couldn't get it to total row columns as I didn't have a value in the column field (Iam adding only one column from each sheet. ...and I couldn't add the lifetime date to the mix cause I couldn't get it to recognize it as number (they are constant numbers manually added. so I went back to the formula, Here's what I ended up with

Comment: Here's the formula, but I still have a problem...     =SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(INDIRECT("'"&A5:A16&"'!A4:A500"),C7,INDIRECT("'"&A5:A16&"'!H4:H500")))      when I fill this down the column it changes not only criteria (which is what I want), but the sheet reference position (A5:A16), so I had to manually change 400 entries to correct it, but now I think new added rows will not resolve automatically,  how do I get the fill down to not change that value?

Comment: FIXED!  I changed the reference to SHEET NAMES as a range . It didn't work until I transposed the range in the data reference to TRANSPOSE(ListsE$3:E$14)   Not sure why but looking at other posts, this came up.   but when I went back to look at it, the TRANSPOSE is gone......  =SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(INDIRECT("'"&SheetList&"'!A4:A500"),B4,INDIRECT("'"&SheetList&"'!H4:H500")))                                                       Now if I could just reference the cell A4:A500 and H4:H500 as a table range I wouldn't have this upper bounds of 500. ........but this makes me happy;)